# SQL Union, вторая часть запроса не исполняется

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `ALL` 
FROM `logs` WHERE `base` = 1 
UNION  
COUNT(*) AS `today` 
FROM `logs` 
WHERE `base` = 1 
AND `unixTime` - 86400 > 1482908996
```

Итогом возвращается только набор из ALL, без today.

В чем может быть проблема, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А почему не `UNION ALL`? Вам надо вернуть 2 счётчика, которые между собой почти не связаны, я так понимаю? А почему не отдельными выборками? Возможно, вам ваш вопрос кажется ясным, но стороны как-то не особо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте `UNION ALL`. Простой `UNION` — это `UNION DISTINCT`.

Также возможно, что Вы просто забываете, что получаете ДВЕ записи из одного поля каждая, и смотрите только первую запись.

И ещё: давать имя полю второго запроса бессмысленно, оно будет проигнорировано.

**UPD:** Если же нужно получить ОДНУ запись с ДВУМЯ полями, то

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `ALL`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `unixTime` - 86400 > 1482908996 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `today`
FROM `logs` 
WHERE `base` = 1
```

**UPD2:** Поскольку СУБД - MySQL, запрос можно упростить:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `ALL`,
       SUM(`unixTime` - 86400 > 1482908996) AS `today`
FROM `logs` 
WHERE `base` = 1
```

Comment: Соответственно, нужную выборку через UNION мне не реализовать?

Comment: Обновил ответ для варианта с одной записью. PS. Вы же не определили чётко, что собственно нужно...

Comment: @ВиталийRS А "нужную" - это какую ? вы бы в вопросе показали как должен выглядеть результат и заодно указали какая у вас СУБД.

Comment: @Mike по частям запроса же видно. Выборку всех записей с указанным параметром, и с фильтром по столбцу

Comment: @ВиталийRS Приведенный в вопросе запрос делает именно то как в нем написано - дает один столбец с именем ALL в котором одна строка - количество записей для base=1 и еще одна строка с количеством еще и для определенного времени. Если вам так и надо - две строки, которые не отличить друг от друга (не понятно какая из них какое количество). А если надо не так, а как то по другому - то напишите как именно надо. Вот вам вторым вариантом предлагают 2 колонки

Comment: @ВиталийRS Я же дважды написал о разнице между одной записью с двумя полями и двумя записями с одним полем - и всё равно Вы упорно её игнорируете. И вопрос об используемой РСУБД - тоже проигнорирован.

Comment: @Mike что бы в первом столбце - все записи, где `base = 1`, во второй `base = 1 AND unixTime - 86400 > 1482908996`

Comment: @Akina субд MySQL

Comment: Ну тогда и текст запроса будет попроще. Обновил ответ.